# How to make div elements appear inline with a flex direction of column?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am trying to get the text input on the same line as the h1 tag inline then display it as a flex-direction of column. But it only seems to want to set all the inputs in a line and with the h1 on top which is not what I want.

Here is what I mean.
[image]

here is the desired output:
[image]

```css
.contactuscontent{
          border: 1px solid pink;
          display: flex;
      }
    
    
    .contactusinput {
        display: inline-flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        border: 1px solid purple;
    }
```

```html
<div class="contactuscontent">
          <div class="contactusinput">
            <div class="name"><h1>Name</h1> <input type="text"> </div>
            <div class="email"><h1>Email</h1> <input type="text"> </div>
            <div class="refer"><h1>How did you find us</h1> <input type="text"> </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look into semantics of HTML, `<h1>` is used for headlines.

If you want to add labels for input fields you should use `<label for="...">`. You can style the any tag in any way you want so default styling should not be a reason to use a tag at all.

```css
.contactuscontent {
  border: 1px solid pink;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.contactusinput {
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid purple;
}

.contactusinput>div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.contactusinput label {
  width: 200px;
}

.contactusinput input,
.contactusinput textarea {
  width: 200px;
  padding: 3px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="contactuscontent">
  <div class="contactusinput">
    <div class="name"><label for="name">Name</label> <input type="text" id="name" name="name"> </div>
    <div class="email"><label for="email">Email</label> <input type="text" id="email"> </div>
    <div class="refer"><label for="howtofind">How did you find us</label> <textarea id="howtofind"> </textarea> </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because `h1` is a block element, and since it's inside an un-styled div, it will push the `input` in a new line.

If you make the `div` that wraps the `h1` and the `input` as flexbox, it will look similar to the image:

```
.contactusinput div {
  display: flex;
}
```

You don't need flexbox on any of the parents for this to work.

To push inputs in the same line you can add `min-width` to the `h1`:

```
h1 {
  min-width: 200px;
}
```

You will need to apply different styling to smaller screens, likely removing the `min-width` and showing the `h1` in a column instead of row.

Here is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9tfy6mzo/)

By the way, heading elements `h1`-`h6` aren't meant for this. You generally want to have only one `h1` in the entire site. The better option to use here would be [label](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp).

Answer (score 1):

To make the design you want, it is needed to set `flexbox` on the div which contains `input` and `h1`.

So in this case, there will be 3 divs to have the flexbox design and all of them are the direct childs of `.contactusinput` selector.

So on `style`, you can set the `.contactusinput > div` (direct div child of `.contactusselector`) style to `flexbox` as follows.

```css
.contactuscontent {
  border: 1px solid pink;
  display: flex;
}

.contactusinput {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid purple;
}

.contactusinput > div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="contactuscontent">
          <div class="contactusinput">
            <div class="name"><h1>Name</h1> <input type="text"> </div>
            <div class="email"><h1>Email</h1> <input type="text"> </div>
            <div class="refer"><h1>How did you find us</h1> <input type="text"> </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Amazing. Thank you!